# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.dll

Tags: c#, dll

I am trying to build the project in my clients machine and i am getting this error. Its working fine in local

```
            Error   37  Could not load file or assembly 
    'file:///C:\Users\Administrator.INTERNAL\Downloads\RS\ABTMedicalNew.com\packages\EnterprizeCaching\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.dll' or one of its dependencies.    
         Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)   
C:\Users\Administrator.INTERNAL\Downloads\RS\ABTMedicalNew.com\Libraries\ABTMedical.Services\SGEN   ABTMedical.Services
```

Comment: Have you verified that the file exists on the deployed machine? If not, it could be worth looking at the referenced DLL and seeing if the path is correct.

Comment: ya it is there in the deployed machine but still throwing the error

Comment: Notice the error says "or one of its dependencies".   Did you use something like ILSpy to check for other assemblies that Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.dll uses?

Comment: it depends on Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common and its also there